# In Elassandra not able to access elastic search url

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

**Hi, I am new to Elassandra. I want to make setup(windows 10) and hit queries from elastic search url in stored documents. I have installed Elassandra and start it is working fine but i am not able to access elastic search url. I also tried to configure host and http.port in elasticsearch.yml but it did not work.**

from bin i am running cassandra -f -e. here is no error in logs but still not able to access ES on localhost:9200

*Please help me out on the steps.
Thanks in advance.*

Comment: any installation doc u following

Comment: Not any specific, I just took .zip archive from (https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/releases) and go to bin folder and start cassandra ps file. afterwards created few keyspaces and tables which all are fine. Only the elastic search side i have issue.